# How can I filter MS Teams channels with connectors configured for channel using graph API c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to filter List channels MS graph API with connectors configured for the channels using graph API in C#.

How should I achieve this?

Is it possible?

Update :-
I am using **graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams** to get all teams that user is part of. And **graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams{teamUID}/channels** to get all channels of a team that user is part of.

We are using C# for coding & Microsoft.graph Nuget package

But I want to use $filter ODataParameter for filtering list of channels with connectors configured for channel.

Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks & Regards,

Renuka Patil

Comment: Hi, are you accessing the GraphAPI as an application, using application, admin verified token, or are you accessing it using end user's token? If you're accessing it as an user, you can use this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams` to get all teams that user is part of. And this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamUID}/channels` to get all channels of a team that user is part of.

Comment: If  you're using it as an application, please take a look at [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in Microsoft docs. Also, please make sure that info you get is NOT shown to the end user, as it might include confidential channels and stuff, that might not be in line with you're company's privacy policy.

Comment: Hi, you can use below graph api to get channel details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. However the response object will not contain details regarding connectors configured for the channels.